# Como passar vetores de uma controller pra outra no cakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2

Gostaria de saber se tem como ir de uma controller para outra passando parâmetros.

Por exemplo:

Eu tenho um array com informações em uma view e gostaria de mandá-lo para uma outra controller. Como fazer isso?

Comment: Não é só fazer `$this->Session->set('dados', $meuArray);` ?